# Core PHP add to cart for storing multiple products using session

Tags: php

I want to insert multiple products in cart table for our e-commerce project. Here I attached cart page screenshots at below. Kindly check

[image]

Product Details page :

```
<form method="POST" action=" "> 
        <div class="inner-sec">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 banner">             
             </div> 
           </div>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="inner-head clearfix">
              <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1">
              <h1>Hinite Capsules 
              </h1> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row" style=" padding-bottom: 15px">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div id="breadcrum" >
                <a class="ancher" href="index.php">Home</a> » <a class="ancher" href="products.php">Products</a> »  Hinite Capsules              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/products/920535865hinite_caps.png" class="img-thumbnail" style="border-radius: 40px;box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="exTab1">
              <ul  class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active">
                  <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Indications</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Composition</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Mode Of Action</a>
                </li> 
              </ul> 
              <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
                 <ul> 
                    <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Erectile Dysfunction<br/></li> 
                    <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Aphrodisiac<br/></li> 
                    <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Loss Of Libido<br/></li>                       
                    <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Premature Ejaculation<br/></li>  
                    <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Ejaculatory Insufficiency<br/></li>   
                 </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="2a"> 
                   <ul>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Kali Musli (Curculigo Orchioides)<br/>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Ashwagandha (Withania Somnifera)<br/>                          
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Gokshur (Terbulus Terristris)<br/>                          
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Kokilaksha(Hygrophila Schulli)<br/></li>                           
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Kapikachhu (Mucuna Puriens)<br/></li>                           
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Jatiphala (Myristica Frangrans)<br/> </li>                          
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Kesar (Crocus Sativus)<br/> </li>                          
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Shigru (Moringa Oleifera)<br/>  </li>                         
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Vidarikand (Pueraria tuberosa)<br/></li>                           
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Kalimirch(Piper Nigrum)<br/></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
                  <ul>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hinite Help to synthesize Anabolic hormones which Produce & Retain Nitric Oxide in the body<br/></li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>which Triggers Natural Erectile Process Increases Testosterone Levels and Elevates Libido Phyto constituent Withaferin-A in hinite Increases Vigor<br/></li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hinite caps improves mental stability strength enthusiasm and Retains vitality. Elevates and enhances overall male performance.<br/></li>
                 </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <h3 class="headingh3">Available Pack</h3>
              <ul class="mls" style="text-align: center;">  
                <li>10's</li>
                <li>30’s</li>
                <li>60’s</li>
                <li>90’s</li>            
              </ul>
          </div>  
          <div class="col-md-6 advantages">
              <h3 class="headingh31">Advantage</h3>
              <ul class="advtd">

                  <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>In Management Of Erectile Dysfunction<br/> </li>                
                  <li><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Loss Of Libido<br/></li> 
              </ul> 
          </div> 
        </div>  
        <div class="text-center">  
            <button class="btn-borderblackdark btn btn_enquiry" name="submit" value=""add> Add To Cart</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Here I displayed two products id and got it from post method. My coding will display at below cases :

PHP Code with SQL Query :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $actual_price=$_POST['actual_price'];
    $gst=$_POST['gst'];
    $granttotal=$_POST['granttotal'];  
for($i=1;$i<=count($_POST['arraycount']);$i++)
    {      
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cart`(`actual_price`,`gst`,`granttotal`,`joinon`)VALUES ('$actual_price','$gst','$granttotal','".date('Y-m-d')."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $lastid = mysql_insert_id(); 
        $product_id=$_POST['product_id'.$i];   
        mysql_query("UPDATE `cart` SET `product_id` = '$product_id' WHERE `cart_id` ='$lastid'"); 
    }

}
```

Cart page :

```
<form action="" class="form1" method="POST"> 
<div class="cart-table table-responsive mb-40">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="pro-remove">Remove</th>
                <th class="pro-thumbnail">Image</th>
                <th class="pro-title">Product</th>
                <th class="pro-price">Price</th>
                <th class="pro-quantity">Quantity</th> 
                <th class="pro-subtotal"> Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <?php 
                $cartid = $_GET['proid'];  
                $sqlpd = mysql_query("select * from orderdetail LEFT JOIN products ON orderdetail.product_id = products.product_id where sessionid='$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());  
                while($getpd = mysql_fetch_array($sqlpd)){
                        $orderdetail_id = $getpd['orderdetail_id'];
                        $product_id = $getpd['product_id'];
                    ?> 
            <tr>
                <td class="pro-remove"><a href="add_cart.php?delete=delete&orderid=<?php echo $orderdetail_id;?>"  name="cart_remove" id="cart_remove" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                <td class="pro-thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="admin/<?php echo $getpd['medium_image'];?>" height="50" width="50">
                </td> 
                <td class="pro-title">
                    <input type="text" name="arraycount[]">
                    <input type="text" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id?>">
                    <?php
                        $get = mysql_query("select * from products where product_id='$product_id'");
                        $con = mysql_fetch_array($get);

                 echo $con['item_name'];?></td>
                <td class="pro-price"><span class="price"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?></span></td>

                <td class="pro-quantity">
                    <input type="number" class="cardqty-1 quantity" id="quantity" min="1" value="1" name="quantity" style="width:50px;">
                    <a href="javascript:void();" class="updatecart" data-id="1" data-prd_id="380" data-rowid="c2b5d53083a7597dd75ac36d9fd93581"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td class="pro-subtotal"><span class="total ttotal"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?></span></td> 
            </tr>

            <?php 

                $actual_price += $getpd['actual_price']; 
                $gst = ($actual_price*12)/100 ;
                $granttot = $actual_price + $gst; 
            }?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th >Sub Total</th> 
            <th class="pro-subtotal text-center"><span class="total last_subtotal"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo  number_format($actual_price,2);?></span></th> 


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th >GST(12%)</th> 
            <th class="pro-subtotal text-center"><span class="total gst"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo  number_format($gst,2);?></span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th >Grand Total</th> 
            <th class="pro-subtotal text-center"><span class="total grant_total"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo  number_format($granttot,2);?></span></th>
        </tr>


            <input type="text" name="actual_price" value="<?php echo $actual_price;?>">
            <input type="text" name="gst" value="<?php echo $gst;?>">
            <input type="text" name="granttotal" value="<?php echo $granttot;?>">

    </tfoot>
    </table>
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 d-flex">
        <div class="cart-summary">
            <div class="cart-summary-button">
                <a href="checkout.php">
                    <button class="checkout-btn" name="submit">Checkout</button>
                </a>
                <button class="update-btn"><a href="buyproducts.php">Continue</a></button> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert the multiple products in cart table. Kindly help me. I am new for E-Commerce

Comment: Post the code for add.php and checkout.php too.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly your code is sql inject'able so you should use PDO or MySQLi for safe-query.**

**You shouldn't update data from user except quantity (cause i can now edit source and set price what i want to).**

for tempiorary database you can use just `$_SESSION` variable, so every user has own cart and without putting it to database (self destroy on expire session).

simples add/update product: `$_SESSION['card'][$productID] = $quantity`

delete: `unset($_SESSION['card'][$productID])`

on every add/update/delete you can recalculate price: `$_SESSION['cardPrice'] +|- $productPrice` and got secure way